# Dynamic object field assign by another model

Tags: angularjs

I have a task:

dynamicly generate 2 inputs calls "name of field" and "value of field" and then put data to object in $scope

example

first input value is "angrular"
second input value is "awesome"

as a result I get custom object with field "angular" and value "awesome"

P.S. Sry for poor level of English

Comment: Can you please clarify your question and also please post any relevant code that you have tried to solve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this only with markup, making use of the directives `ng-model` and `ng-change`:

```
<div ng-app>
  <input ng-change="obj[propName] = propValue" ng-model="propName"/>
  <input ng-change="obj[propName] = propValue" ng-model="propValue"/>

  <div>Result: {{ obj }}</div>
</div>
```

... though you said "dynamically generate 2 inputs", which may imply the task involves having the ability to add multiple properties to the result object. This [live example](http://codepen.io/nicooga/pen/KdOVWR) shows a way to do that.

Check the docs:

- [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)
- [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)